# How ofter fetch data from server

Tags: angularjs

I'm pretty new with angularjs and I'm wriring my first application.
I'd like to know if there is a specific best practice about how often I should pull data from the server when I have to deal with big dataset. Is it better to pull one big JSON dataset and make a single call to the server, or it's advisable to fetch small bunch of data with multiple requests?
I try to explain. My application is now fetching from the server all the JSON data required by the application when the main page loads. It's a lot of stuff (about 3MB). Then it never fetches any other data, I can apply filters to the data and sorting it, all it's done client-side with no interaction with the server.
Now, is it worth to fetch few data at the beginning and then, based on the applied filters, re-fetch the data from the server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the specific requirements and usage patterns. If you are worried on quick load times, there are patterns similar to the ones used with `jQuery.dataTables`, which allow for super-quick loading of data, relying on server-side filtering.

If you have good cacheability (data is the same for all users) and no worries for long load times, go for the eager load (and use a filesystem-based cache with nginx serving the cached data).

In general, having local copies of the whole database is only useful when you can't do the work server-side, as RDBMS are much better at data analysis than any javascript implementation.

Comment: It makes sense. I just wanted to make sure not going against the MV* javascript application paradigm which, if I'm not wrong, encourages developers to move the full application to the client

Comment: The full app, not the full data! You still have a database system, which manages the data. Moving some parts of the app to the client is like not having business logic in stored procedures in the database. More manageable, and more scalable when applicable. But if this scaling means to clone the entire database each time...